# Should equations and other mathematical expressions be written in quotes?

Tags: soft-question

Should equations and other mathematical statements be written in quotes? Like $s=t$ and $s < t$, or like "$s=t$" and "$s<t$"?

Comment: I do not understand this question. Also it looks more like a https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ question. Why do you feel the desire to put quotes? Simple answer: No.

Comment: Obviously not in ordinary mathematical writing, so in what contexts?

Comment: No, they shouldn't be written in quotes.

Comment: I am talking about the use-mention distinction.

Comment: Why on *earth* would you put them in quotes? "I am talking about the use-mention distinction."  What use-mention distinction?

Comment: Equations that are mentioned in the sense of use-mention distinction are often labeled as (1), (1.1) or maybe (3.1.2) and then mentioned as Equation (1) or Eqn. (1.1) or Eq 3.1.2.

Comment: When I write $s=t$ I am using it, not mentioning it.  -1 and vote to close because this is not mathematics.  It may be English, it may be Philosophy, it isn't Mathematics.

Comment: @RossMillikan I apologize. I didn't realize it would be inappropriate for math stack exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you find in your math texts?  Normally, we do not use quotes.  Unless it is a place where we would use quotes anyway...

> "Tom," the teacher said,  "what is the solution?"
> Tom replied, "$x=5$."

**added**
The OP comments he is talking talking about the use-mention distinction.  As far as I can tell, in mathematics we do not even normally use quotation marks for that.  For example in a definition, we do not use quotation marks like this

> Define "$\sqrt{x}\;$" as the principal value of $x^{1/2}$.

No, we just do it like this,

> Define $\sqrt{x}\;$ as the principal value of $x^{1/2}$.

which may be confusing sometimes.

Here is an example of confusion.  Since $\frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$,
is it an error to say

> The numerator of $\frac{2}{6}$ is $2$.

?  How about saying

> The numerator of "$\frac{2}{6}$" is $2$.

meaning the fraction we see there, not the number represented by it.  Similar usages:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \quad \text{is an integer}
\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \quad \text{is a convergent series}
\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \quad \text{is a difficult concept for beginners}
$$